# Improve the neural network by analyzing the loss curve

Tags: keras, lstm

I builted some network based on LSTM. I tuneded parameters. The results are shown in the figure and are not impressive.

How to understand what is bad? Is the dataset bad or the network is not well built?

[image: loss curves]

Answer (score 0):

Since validation loss decreased initially and later increased what you're experiencing is **model overfitting**.

Since training loss kept decreasing, your model has learnt training set excessively and now model is not generalizing well. Due to this validation loss increased.

To avoid overfitting, you need to **regularize** your model. You can use `L1` or `L2` regularization techniques. Additionally, you can also try `dropout` in your model.

Now coming to your question: 
If the dataset is of good quality i.e. it is annotated well and it surely has features which could give result, then dataset and model hand-in-hand decides the quality of the predictions.

Since you're using RNNs that consists a good numbers of parameters, make sure that dataset is also huge to avoid RNNs overfitting on a small dataset. If available dataset is small, start with a small deep learning with less parameters (you can build a small neural network) and gradually scale up the model until you're satisfied with the prediction scores.

You can also refer this: https://towardsdatascience.com/rnn-training-tips-and-tricks-2bf687e67527

Comment: Are exists automatic ways to check the quality of the dataset?

Comment: When using LSTM, what is the best way to scale input features? -1 .. 1 or 0 ..1?